# SQL Server 2014 - Give user permission to run sp_refreshview

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I need to give a user the required permission to run sp_refreshview for a specific database on our server.  I've tried adding the user to the db_executor role but that only gave them access to certain stored procedures.

Am I looking to accomplish something that is impossible for SQL Server permissions or am I just looking in the wrong places?  Thank you in advance for any guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Per the sp_refreshview msdn library page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187821.aspx):

> Permissions
>   Requires ALTER permission on the view and REFERENCES permission on common language runtime (CLR) user-defined types and XML schema collections that are referenced by the view columns.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful reply MguerraTorres.  This does tell me what permissions I need to accomplish this task.  However, I cannot seem to add REFERENCES for the XML Schema Collections.  I receive an error that the privilege is not compatible with the object.